# Could not load file or assembly. When multiple project is running. (MVC)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

Suddenly I start having: Could not load file or assembly if I run another project on IIS on the same dev machine.

If I rebuild it gets good again, but as soon as I visit the other project, the trubble is back.

I have not seen this before.

For now it is:

Could not load file or assembly 'Owin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f0ebd12fd5e55cc5' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

But it seems it can also be another Assembly, like the project looses access as soon as the other project start to do something .

Any good ideas here ?

I use MVC (not core)

Best regards and thanks.